# PHP & JavaScript : non-working second script

Tags: php, javascript

I'm getting crazy. 
In a very simple PHP file, with no security consideration as it is for internal use only from a trusted couple of people, I set two JS alerts. Very very basic.
We have an IF with an alert, then an ELSE with the second alert.

First one triggers when required fields are empty, second one should trigger when everything is OK, just to let the user know that the form was posted. 
Excepted that this second alert never triggers.

Let me paste the code :

```
<?php
// Connexion à la base de données
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***', '***', '***');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}


// Concaténation des données des checkboxes iRules avant exécution
if (isset($irules)){
    $irules = implode( ", ", $_POST['irules'] ); 
}
else
{
    $irules = "default";
}

// Si des champs importants sont vides, l'utilisateur reçoit une alerte et les données ne sont pas envoyées
if (empty($_POST['url']) || empty($_POST['nom_vip']) || empty($_POST['ip_vip']))
{
    ?>

    <script>
        Javascript:alert('Merci de remplir tous les champs !')
        document.location.replace("index.php");
    </script>

    <?php
}
else
{
    // Insertion des données à l'aide d'une requête préparée
    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO creation_vs (Protocol, Url, Alias_DNS, Virtual_Server_Name, Virtual_Server_IP_Port, OneConnect_Profile, HTTP_Profile, SSL_Client_Profile, Certificat_Name, SNAT_Pool, Default_Persistence_Profile, Pool_Name, Health_Monitor, Members_Ip_Port, Load_Balancing_Method, iRules, Comments) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

    $req->execute(array($_POST['protocole'], $_POST['url'], $_POST['nom_vip'], $_POST['nom_vs'], $_POST['ip_vip'], $_POST['profil_oneconnect'], $_POST['profil_http'], $_POST['profil_ssl_client'], $_POST['nom_certificat'], $_POST['pool_snat'], $_POST['persistance'], $_POST['nom_pool_vs'], $_POST['health_monitor'], $_POST['members_ip_port'], $_POST['methode_LB'], $irules, $_POST['commentaires']));

    ?>
        <script>
            Javascript:alert('Instance ajoutee ! Merci.');
        </script>
    <?php

    header('Location: index.php'); 
}
?>
```

I've made some tests:

- moving the second script just below the first one : NOK
- permuting both scripts : problem is still the same, first script in the flow works, second one doesn't

Do you see any error in this piece of code ? Nothing is optimized but this is a dev version that I'd like to get functional before improving the code, so please be indulgent ;)

Thank you.

Comment: try moving the header() function call above javascript statement

Comment: 1st: this website is not for debugging purpose, SO is there for that ;). 2nd: headers cannot be sent *after* the body. 3rd: does `Javascript:alert` even work?!

Comment: @MartinMandl : I just tried and still not OK (form sends data to sql base without displaying any JS alert).
@FlorianMargaine : my bad ! Let's note it for the next post ;) `Javascript:alert` does work. The whole file works, excepted the second alert. Ok for the header and body order, I'll do a location.replace in JS when the second script will be working (it won't be active until then)

Comment: Why use two methods to redirect? The first one works, why not re-use it? In the first, javascript redirects to index.php _after_ displaying the alert. In the second, the php tries to re-write the header so that the output will not be displayed, the index.php file is output without the alert.

Comment: @enhzflep : thank you. Replacing the PHP header location with the JS redirect did the trick. 
I first set the php redirect and then I added the scripts. I thought it was better to use the PHP one without understanding the way it worked.
You can post your comment as an answer and I will set it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per request,

Why use two methods to redirect? The first one works, why not re-use it? In the first, javascript redirects to index.php *after* displaying the alert. In the second, the php tries to re-write the header so that the output will not be displayed, the index.php file is output without the alert